# Laravel Sitewide search instead of the database

Tags: laravel, search

Im looking for a laravel search function that looks through the entire DOM instead of the database, and if possible provide links to where the searched word can be found. So far all my reading and researches involves searching in databases only. Can someone please point me in the right direction

Comment: Without having the content (in this case your DOM), you can't search it. Your browser doesn't know the other pages of your site exist. If you want to search your site, you need to have a store of it somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

you can send requests to other pages that you want to read content with the package called, Guzzle and get the answer. and show it to the user. it is a PHP package

https://packagist.org/packages/guzzlehttp/guzzle

so you have:

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $client->request('GET', 'https://api.github.com/repos/guzzle/guzzle');

echo $response->getStatusCode(); // 200
echo $response->getHeaderLine('content-type'); // 'application/json; charset=utf8'
echo $response->getBody(); // '{"id": 1420053, "name": "guzzle", ...}'
```

you can do your search in the `getBody()` method. and show the answer to the user.

Note:

if you want to show the search result without refreshing the page, it's better to do it with JS.
with the fetch method, you can do it. it's better for the search box and show the options to the user.

Comment: im somewhat of a beginner on js, could you please elaborate more on the fetch method?

Comment: @sven this is the link for the fetch method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch you can use js to change the content of your HTML, without refresh the page. first, get new content with fetch and then, replace it with old content with DOM. If you're a beginner programmer, I think it's better, you don't go for "searching in DOM instead of database" with PHP. if you want to do that, go to learn js:  
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PkZNo7MFNFg